# Вывод сообщений одним диалогом

Tags: mysqli, php, sql

Возник вопрос: Как выводить все пришедшие сообщения, допустим от пользователя astafev в один диалог, от другого пользователя в другой диалог и т.д. Подскажите как составить такой SQL запрос ? уже имеется: `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE who='$user_id'`
[image: my messages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Если нужны диалоги только двух пользователей, то достаточно добавить сортировку:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE who in ('$user_id1','$user_id2)
ORDER BY who, <время>
```

Comment: я проверю данный запрос. Мне как бы требуется, как в соц. сети Вконтакте вывод не по 1-му сообщению от 1-го пользователя, а именно создается диалог и в этот диалог приходят все сообщения от определенного пользователя.